# HTAccess Rule for Rewrite URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have url

domainname.com/filename.php?id=45&view=sale

i want to set url as

domainname.com/filename/id/45/view/sale/

Can any one please help.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=(.*)&view=(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*).php$ /$1/id/%1/view/%2 [R]
```

You do want to map this way, right? The other way round is easier.
You may remove the [R] flag. It helps testing.